# Why there is so much issue with the Firefox Driver in the Selenium 3.4.0?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Why there is so much issue with the Firefox Driver in the Selenium 3.0?

When I try using the Action class it doesn't context click(right click), and also I have tried to select multiple options from the list it doesn't select.

```
public class MultipleSelect {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Saurabh\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/selectable/");
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        List<WebElement> selectOption = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/ol/li"));
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(selectOption.size());
        act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).perform();

        for(int i=1;i<8;i++) {
            if(i%2==0) {
                act.click(selectOption.get(i-1)).perform();

                System.out.println(selectOption.get(i-1).getText()+" is Selected");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check with selenium 3.4 and latest firefox/gecko driver?

Comment: Yes you are write there is issue  in`Actions` class while try in geckodriver

Comment: @santhosh kumar, i have latest selenium 3.4 and latest geckodriver 0.18.0. but still facing issue with action class. Do you have any idea about issue resolved or not ?

Comment: The above code tries with Chrome and i am not able to see the contextClick() line... Am i missing some thinsg.

Comment: You spoke about `context click(right click)` and there is no trace of it in your code. Thanks

Comment: yes, thats the different code

Comment: i have just given the program of  selecting the multiple item list, i havent given the program for contextClick().

Comment: Consider bumping up your `Selenium` version to `3.4.0`. Update your question as per your requirement and with your exact manual steps which you are trying to automate along with your research effort please. Thanks

Comment: *Why there is so much issue with the Firefox Driver in the Selenium 3.4.0?* is a good question but not appropriate for SO.  Any answer can't help but be [primarily opinion-based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and so off-topic. You should consider rephrasing your question to narrow the scope to the code problem you supplied in the question.